# Formulario queda atrás de panel con botones

Tags: c#, formularios

Tengo un formulario **MDI** que tiene botones y quiero abrir 
formularios hijos a través de darle click al botón del MDI pero
 cuando me abre esos formulario hijos el formulario queda atrás
 de los botones (los botones están en un panel dentro del MDI) y necesito que queden enfrente

[image: problema con panel]

¿como hago eso? 
o si no se puede ¿cual seria otra solución ?

Answer (score 0):

No puede poner controles en form que actua como MDI Container, deberias definir un menu o toolbar

[Menus and ToolBar Control using C#](http://csharpexpress.blogspot.com.ar/2011/05/menus-and-toolbar-control-using-c.html)

de esta forma las acciones de la toolbar o menu serian quienes lanzan los forms hijos dentro del mdi

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción a la que plantea Leandro, en vez de usar un formulario `MDI` puedes usar un panel y abrir los formularios dentro de ese panel y actuará como un `Formulario MDI`.

Hecha un vistazo a esta respuesta:

[Abrir Formularios dentro de un Panel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130492/69447), fue contestada por el usuario [@Asier Villanueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6088/asier-villanueva), a una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130488/c%C3%B3mo-saber-si-un-formulario-esta-abierto-en-un-panel/130492#130492) que realicé.