# ¿Cómo saber si un formulario esta abierto en un panel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo una **función para abrir los formularios** dentro de un `panel` , necesito **Validar si el formulario esta abierto, para hacer un `BringToFront();`** si el formulario no existe en el panel hacer un `.Show()`

> La función es la siguiente:

```
private void agregarFormPanel(object formularios)
{
     Form formulario = formularios as Form;
     formulario.TopLevel = false;

     panel_contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
     panel_contenedor.Tag = formulario;
     formulario.Show();
}

//Para usarlo: 

agregarFormPanel(new FormularioX());
```

Encontré esta función de una respuesta de SO:

```
private void AbreFormulario(Type formType)
{
    //Se localiza el formulario buscandolo entre los forms abiertos 
    Form formulario = this.MdiChildren.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == formType);
    if (formulario != null)
    {
        //Si la instancia esta minimizada la dejamos en su estado normal
        if (formulario.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            formulario.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        //Si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
        formulario.BringToFront();
        return;
    }
    //Se abre el form
    formulario = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(formType);
    formulario.MdiParent = this;
    formulario.Show();
}

//Uso: 
 AbreFormulario(typeof(FormularioX));
```

Pero esto funciona para un `Formulario MDI`.

> **¿Cómo puedo hacer la validación en la función que abre los formularios en el panel?**

También vi esto:

```
  if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<AquiLaConfiguracion>().Any())
      MessageBox.Show("Form Abierto");
  else
      MessageBox.Show("Form no Abierto");
```

Entorno: Visual Studio 2010 & >NET Netframework 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías crear un método genérico con restricciones para que el tipo usado herede de `Form` y tenga un constructor vacío (`where T : Form, new()`)

De esta forma puedes buscar dentro de la colección `Controls` del panel si existe algún control del tipo especificado. Si existe, lo traes al frente. Si no existe creas una nueva instancia y lo añades al panel como estabas haciendo en tu método:

```
private void AbrirFormulario<T>() where T : Form, new()
{
    Form formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (formulario!=null)
    {
        //Si la instancia esta minimizada la dejamos en su estado normal
        if (formulario.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            formulario.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        //Si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
        formulario.BringToFront();
        return;
    }
    //Se abre el form
    formulario = new T();
    formulario.TopLevel = false;
    panel_contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
    panel_contenedor.Tag = formulario;
    formulario.Show();
}
```

De esta forma para llamarlo te bastaría con hacer:

```
AbrirFormulario<FormularioX>();
```

Comment: Soluciona perfectamente mi problema!

Comment: Luego de la linea de código: `formulario.TopLevel = false;` coloqué esto: `formulario.Location = new Point(( panel_contenedor.Width - formulario.Width ) / 2,
                                            ( panel_contenedor.Height - formulario.Height ) / 2);` para inicialmente abrir el formulario en el centro del panel.

Comment: Excelente aporte, me ayudo a solucionar el mismo problema.