# Abrir un form desde otro Form en un Panel C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy haciendo un programa con Visual Studio 2015, es un proyecto de Windows Form con un diseño UI  bastante bueno, que permite abrir un `Form` dentro de un `Panel` sin abrirlo en una nueva ventana. Eso me genera un inconveniente, ya que por ejemplo, cuando quiero abrir un `Form` y dentro de él con un botón abrir otro `Form`, no encuentro forma de hacerlo, por qué no puedo ocultar o borrar el padre de este último?

Este es mi código:

```
private void AbrirFormInPanel(object formHijo)
    {
        if (this.panelContenedor.Controls.Count > 0)
            this.panelContenedor.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
        Form fh = formHijo as Form;
        fh.TopLevel = false;
        fh.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.panelContenedor.Controls.Add(fh);
        this.panelContenedor.Tag = fh;
        fh.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Podrías compartirnos el código con el que abres nuevos `Forms`?

Comment: Estás haciendo uso de una ventana que funciones como `MDI parent` para que contenga en su interior ventanas?

Comment: Ya coloque el código

Comment: Los forms no pueden ser contenedores de otros forms, salvo que los mismos sean mdi.

Comment: Te recomiendo totalmente no hacer eso. Es posible usando ciertas funciones del API de windows, pero da muchos problemas y estéticamente y a nivel de manejo no es bueno. Por que no creas un control de usuario en lugar de un form?

Comment: Usando `fh.ShowDialog()` en lugar de `fh.Show()` no hace lo que pretendes? quizás no entendí bien lo que necesitas

Answer (score 1):

Hace unos meses realicé una pregunta semejante: [¿Cómo saber si un formulario esta abierto en un panel?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/130488/69447) y con la respuesta me parece que puedes obtener el resultado que deseas.

> Cito la [respuesta original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130492/69447) por [Asier Villanueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6088/asier-villanueva)

Podrías crear un método genérico con restricciones para que el tipo usado herede de `Form` y tenga un constructor vacío (`where T : Form, new()`)

De esta forma puedes buscar dentro de la colección Controls del panel si existe algún control del tipo especificado. Si existe, lo traes al frente. Si no existe creas una nueva instancia y lo añades al panel:

```
private void AbrirFormulario<T>() where T : Form, new()
{
    Form formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (formulario!=null)
    {
        //Si la instancia esta minimizada la dejamos en su estado normal
        if (formulario.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            formulario.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        //Si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
        formulario.BringToFront();
        return;
    }
    //Se abre el form
    formulario = new T();
    formulario.TopLevel = false;
    panel_contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
    panel_contenedor.Tag = formulario;
    formulario.Show();
}
```

De esta forma para llamarlo te bastaría con hacer:

```
AbrirFormulario<FormularioX>();
```

Comment: ¿Hay forma de enviar datos de un formulario a controles de un formulario que se esta abriendo por medio de este método?

Comment: @user190170 Si se puede, en este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/167746/69447, di una respuesta mas detallada que muestra como pasar esos datos via parámetros.