# Cómo puedo pasar Parámetros a Formulario con este Método Genérico?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2010

Tengo este método genérico para abrir formularios dentro de un panel, este método hereda de `Form`, actualmente con la restricción de que tenga un constructor vacío `(where T : Form, new())`

```
private void AbrirFormulario<T>() where T : Form, new()
{
    Form formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (formulario!=null)
    {
        //Si la instancia esta minimizada la dejamos en su estado normal
        if (formulario.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            formulario.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        //Si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
        formulario.BringToFront();
        return;
    }
    //Se abre el form
    formulario = new T();
    formulario.TopLevel = false;
    panel_contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
    panel_contenedor.Tag = formulario;
    formulario.Show();
}
```

De esta forma para llamarlo:

```
AbrirFormulario<FormularioX>();
```

**¿Cómo puedo adaptar esta función para poder pasar parámetros al formulario?**

En este caso necesito pasar dos parámetros al formulario, algo como esto:

```
AbrirFormulario<FormularioX>(parametro1, parametro2);
```

> Pero puede que en lo adelante, necesite utilizar 1/2/3 parámetros dependiendo del formulario.
>
> Los parámetros pueden variar de tipo, ya sea: `bool`, `string`, `int` etc.

**¿Alguna idea de como puedo lograr hacer esto?**, ya sea pasando una lista de parámetros, una lista opcional (como los parámetros opcionales) o algo semejante?

Entorno: Visual Studio 2010 & .NET NetFramework 4.

Comment: @Pikoh los parámetros podrían variar, `bool`, `string` , `int`. En este caso necesito pasar un `bool` y un `string`, Pero como ves  puede que en otra ocasión necesite pasar otro tipo de parámetro, o sin parámetro ninguno. Será posible?

Comment: Bueno, posible es pero todo depende de tus necesidades. Podrias crear un método `private void AbrirFormulario<T>(params object[] args) where T : Form, new()`. Pero deberías crear en los formularios que quieras abrir con este método un constructor personalizado que recibiera tambien `params object[]`.

Comment: @Pikoh Me puedes dar un ejemplo con el método y poner un constructor de la manera que sugieres que reciba ese tipo, por ejemplo: `public form1(object[] params) { ... }`

Comment: @Pikoh de acuerdo, tomate tu tiempo.

Comment: A priori, creo que la forma de hacerlo tendría que implicar crear una clase propia que herede de Form, en la que el constructor que recibe `params object[] parametros` fuera obligatorio. De esa manera, la restriccion sería esta nueva clase,y podrías llamar a este constructor en tu método `AbrirFormulario`

Comment: @Pikoh _en la que el constructor que recibe params object[] parametros fuera obligatorio_ esta parte no la comprendo, o sea si es obligatoria todos mis formularios deberán recibir parámetros? ,  no puedo usarlo así, aclárame tu idea por favor.

Comment: Es un poco complicado explicar en un comentario. Intentaré añadir una respuesta

Comment: Me parece que no es posible usando el constructor, ya que no se puede "configurar" un constructor en un interfaz. Lo que podrías es crear un interfaz con un método que recibiera los parametros a la que llamaras tras crear el formulario, algo como `formulario = new T(); formulario.setParámetros(tusparametros);`

Comment: @Pikoh estoy completamente perdido... Si no quisiera complicarme, puedo crear esas variables publicas dentro del formulario y no usarla como parámetros, pero tampoco tendría acceso a asignar el valor a ellas al llamar el formulario de esta manera `AbrirFormulario<FormularioX>();`

Comment: Mira mi respuesta a ver si te queda mas claro. El tema tiene su miga y he tenido que pensar una manera para simular lo que quieres. Espero que te ayude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solución Final:**

Realmente el mejor enfoque para hacerlo es usar un método factory [`Func<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx) para construir el formulario:

Digamos que tenemos este `Form`, solo para fines de prueba:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form3(bool algunParametro, string algunTitulo)
    {

    }
}
```

Con el método de esta manera:

```
public void AbrirFormulario<T>(Func<T> metodofactory) where T : Form
{
      //Buscar el formulario dentro del panel.
      Form formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
      if (formulario != null)
      {
         //Si la instancia esta minimizada la dejamos en su estado normal
         if (formulario.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
         {
             formulario.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
         }
         //Si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
         formulario.BringToFront();
         return;
     }

     //Se abre el form
     formulario = metodofactory();
     formulario.TopLevel = false;
     panel_contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
     panel_contenedor.Tag = formulario;
     formulario.Show();
}
```

Que luego se llama así:

```
AbrirFormulario(() => new Form1(true, "Titulo"));
AbrirFormulario(() => new Form2());
```

> Observemos cómo también puede dejar fuera la parte `<Form1>` de la llamada `AbrirFormulario`, se infiere!

Con todo el intellisense útil que lo acompaña:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que ahora quedamos con un código de auto-documentación, no importa cómo se construye el formulario, y no está forzando a usar una interfaz.

---

**Problemas al usar `params object[] args`**:

Ahora hay algunas características útiles de auto-documentación sobre el constructor, es decir, que los parámetros tienen nombres. Y usando algo como esto:

```
public void AbrirFormulario<T>(params object[] args) where T : Form
{
    //...
}
```

No le da a quien llama información sobre cuáles son los "argumentos", a qué orden pertenecen o qué significan. Entonces cuando lo llamamos así:

```
AbrirFormulario<Form1>(true, "Titulo");
```

El Intellisense no lo ayuda porque solo muestra que necesita pasar algunos (o ningún) parámetro(s) al método.

Comment: Esta solución es mucho mejor que usar reflection. Se podría argumentar que para acabar haciendo esto, tampoco es muy necesario tener que crear ese método usando genéricos, pero mi enhorabuena por investigar y dar con una solución interesante. Para mi esto es [es.so] :)

Comment: @Pikoh muchas gracias, como te comente me surge una pregunta mas, podrías ayudarme? En el método para buscar el formulario dentro del panel utilizo esto:
`Form formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();` a modo de evitar que el mismo formulario se abra mas de una vez, **¿Cómo podría bajo cierta condición permitir que un formulario especifico si se pueda abrir mas de una vez dentro del panel?**

Por ejemplo que el `Form3` si permita abrirlo todas las veces que el usuario quiera, pero los demas `Form1`, `Form2` solo permita una sola instancia?

Comment: Bueno,esa sería otra ventaja de mi enfoque con Interfaces. Podrías incorporar al interfaz una propiedad(`permitirVariasInstancias` por ejemplo) y de esa manera comprobar esta propiedad. Con esta solución que planteas, la unica solución que veo es, o incorporar a los formularios una propiedad como la que te digo auqnue no este forzada por una interfaz, o bien crearte una lista con los tipos a los que quieres permitir varias instancias y comprobar dicho tipo contra la lista en tu metodo de búsqueda de formularios.

Comment: @Pikoh Justamente he pensado en eso `permitirVariasInstancias` pero no se como implementarlo, Estoy estructura la pregunta con todos los detalles, para formular una nueva pregunta y no seguir con este tema en esta pregunta, para que no se salga de contexto, por favor, cuando yo realice la pregunta, me gustaría que me ayudará, le avisaré cuando la publique.

Comment: Otra opción muy sencilla que se me acaba de ocurrir y que se usaba mucho hace tiempo, es usar la propiedad `Tag`. Dicha propiedad es de tipo object y es heredada via Control. Puedes usar `form1.tag="Si"` y luego comprobarla. De esa manera,además,no se restrigiría a un tipo de formulario sino a una instancai cualquiera

Comment: @Pikoh si me parece sencillo de esa manera y me gustaría aplicarla, pero tendría que cumplir otra condición a parte del valor que contenga el formulario en la propiedad `Tag`, he realizado [la pregunta aqui esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/167825/69447) por favor dele un vistazo a ver como puedo ayudarme.

Answer (score 4):

Me parece muy interesante esta pregunta, por eso voy a tratar de dar una opción aunque tal vez no es la ideal.

El problema principal es que no hay ninguna manera de forzar un constructor específico en C#. Eso nos deja con una posible opción (tal vez haya mas).

Mi propuesta es crear un Interfaz para crear un método que permita recibir los parámetros. Este es un ejemplo:

```
public interface IFormulario
{
    void InicializarParametros(params object[] parametros);
}
```

Aquí definimos un método,  `InicializarParametros` que deben cumplir los formularios que implementen este interfaz.

Posteriormente, en los formularios que deban ser llamados desde el formulario genérico, añadimos el interfaz en su definición, y el método obligatorio:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IFormulario
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void InicializarParametros(params object[] parametros)
    {
        if (parametros.Length==2)
        {
            string parametro1 = parametros[0].ToString();
            int parametro2 = (int)parametros[1];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("El número de parámetros es incorrecto");
        }

    }       
}
```

Ahora definimos el método genérico para abrir los formularios de la siguiente manera:

```
private void AbrirFormulario<T>(params object[] args) where T : Form,IFormulario,  new()
{
    Form formulario;
    formulario = new T();
    ((IFormulario)formulario).InicializarParametros(args);
    formulario.Show();
}
```

Por último, la forma de usarlo sería la siguiente:

```
AbrirFormulario<Form1>("a", 2);
AbrirFormulario<Form1>("a", 2, "b");
AbrirFormulario<Form1>();
```

Ten en cuenta que tal como he definido el método `InicializarParametros`, los ejemplos 2 y 3 darán una excepción por un numero incorrecto de parámetros. Eres tu el que debe controlarlo en cada caso.

Comment: Disculpa la demora, he intentado probarlo, pero de este modo, tendría que implementar la interfaz, en todos los formularios. Son muchos formularios, tendría que reestructurar todo nuevamente.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez Bueno,la reestructuración tampoco es muy grande,simplemente añadir ´IFormulario´ a cada form y añadir el metodo que son tres lineas. Yo creo que no hay otra forma de hacerlo pero espera a ver si alguien te dice otra cosa.

Comment: Tengo un sistema que contiene 5 modulos, entonces en el modulo que cree la interface es el modulo que contiene el menú principal, y este modulo entonces tiene como referencias los demas que es donde estan los formularios, si creo la interfaz en el modulo donde esta el menú principal, no tengo acceso desde los demás módulos para usarlo en los formularios, y si intento a cada modulo agregarle el modulo donde esta el menú no se puede porque hace una relación circular. Alguna idea de que hacer?

Comment: No se si te entiendo muy bien,el interfaz debe estar en su propia clase y debes poder hacer referencia a el desde cualquier sitio.

Comment: Sucede lo siguiente: Son 5 Modulos cada modulo tiene un espacio de nombre distinto. La clase de la interfaz la tengo ejemplo en el modulo 1 que el del menu principal desde donde se acceden a todos los formularios de los demas módulos, entonces en el módulo 2 no tengo acceso a esa clase interfas del modulo 1, ya que esta en otro espacio de nombre, para esto tendria que agregar ese modulo como referencia, pero se haria una relacion circular y el visual studio no lo permite, se puede crear la clase con varios `namespace`?

Comment: Ahí empieza a complicarse un poco la cosa. En ese caso, yo tal vez lo que haría sería meter el interfaz en su propio namespace, como una librería, y meteria referencias a esa dll en cualquier sitio donde necesites usar la interfaz.

Comment: Creo que eso voy a tener que hacer entonces, me ha ayudado bastante tu respuesta, esperaré un poco mas a ver si alguien mas coloca alguna respuesta, de lo contrario, da por hecho que marcaré tu respuesta como aceptada. Muchas gracias!

Comment: He posteado una solución usando reflexión, gracias a un usuario de SO Ingles, he decidido compartirla aquí, Saludos y de veras de agradezco tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Al final he decidido hacerlo con [Reflection (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). En ese caso, eliminando la restricción `new()` para permitir formularios sin constructores sin parámetros:

```
public void AbrirFormulario<T>(params object[] args) where T : Form
```

Ahora, para crear la instancia, usar [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
T formulario = default(T);

if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
    formulario = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
else
    formulario = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
```

De modo que la **solución completa** quedaría de esta manera:

```
public void AbrirFormulario<T>(params object[] args) where T : Form
{
    Form formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (formulario !=null)
    {
        //Si la instancia esta minimizada la dejamos en su estado normal
        if (formulario.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            formulario.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
        //Si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
        formulario.BringToFront();
        return;
    }
    //Se abre el form
    if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
        formulario = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    else
        formulario = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
    formulario.TopLevel = false;
    panel_contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
    panel_contenedor.Tag = formulario;
    formulario.Show();
}
```

Y para usarlo de estas formas:

```
object[] args = new object[] { "a", true };

AbrirFormulario<Form1>(args);
AbrirFormulario<Form2>("b", 2, false);
AbrirFormulario<Form3>();
```

> MSDN:
>
> - [Activator.CreateInstance Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx)
> - [Activator.CreateInstance Method (Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx)
> - [Activator.CreateInstance Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Es una opción muy interesante, aunque reflection debe ser usado con cuidado. Me alegro de que hayas dado con una solución a tu gusto :)

Comment: @Pikoh si estuve leyendo un poco sobre reflection, es un tema interesante.

Comment: @Pikoh Disculpe que le moleste nuevamente, finalmente creo que he encontrado la menera mas adecuada de hacerlo la he posteado si desea darle un vistazo, y me gustaría hacerle una pequeña pregunta más a usted, es algo breve si no le molesta

Answer (score 0):

Se podría sobre escribir el método y aumentar params para los parámetros dinámicos.

```
    private void AbrirFormulario<T>() where T : Form, new()
    {
        AbrirFormulario<T>(null);
    }

    private void AbrirFormulario<T>(params object[] parametros) where T : Form, new()
    {
        Form formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (formulario != null)
        {
            //Si la instancia esta minimizada la dejamos en su estado normal
            if (formulario.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                formulario.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
            //Si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
            formulario.BringToFront();
            return;
        }
        //Se abre el form
        formulario = new T();

        //Lógica para aplicar los parámetros, casteas a sus tipos correspondientes a como enviaste los parámetros.

        formulario.TopLevel = false;
        panel_contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
        panel_contenedor.Tag = formulario;
        formulario.Show();
    }
```

y su manera de uso

```
AbrirFormulario<Form>(5, false, 10); 
AbrirFormulario<Form>();
```

Comment: De esta forma, el método siempre tendría que ser parámetrizado, no podría usar el método si el constructor no tiene parámetros, ademas de que los parámetros su método son todos de un mismo tipo y esto pueden variar [mire este  comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167048/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-pasar-par%c3%a1metros-a-formulario-con-este-m%c3%a9todo-gen%c3%a9rico-c/167057#comment313844_167048)

Comment: No Ricardo. De que te sirve recibir los parámetros en `AbrirFormulario` si luego no les usas para crear el formulario? :)

Comment: Gracias por el intento de ayudarme pero la llamada del método de esta forma `AbrirFormulario<MyForm>(5, false, 10);` no funciona, genera error en el compilador.

Comment: Error:  `must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'AbrirFormulario<T>(params object[])'`