# ¿Cómo permitir abrir varias instancias de un Formulario bajo cierta condición especificada?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios, visual-studio-2010

*(Explicaré lo más detallado posible para que puedan entender de forma mas clara la pregunta)*

Tengo este método para abrir formularios dentro de un panel, con el cual puedo permitir formularios que contengan constructores con párametros y sin parámetros, esto basado en esta pregunta [Cómo puedo pasar Parámetros a Formulario con este Método Genérico?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/167048/69447) que realicé aqui en SO.

```
public void AbrirFormulario<T>(Func<T> metodofactory) where T : Form
{
      //Buscar el formulario dentro del panel.
      Form formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
      if (formulario != null)
      {
         //Si la instancia esta minimizada la dejamos en su estado normal
         if (formulario.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
         {
             formulario.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
         }
         //Si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
         formulario.BringToFront();
         return;
     }

     //Se abre el form
     formulario = metodofactory();
     formulario.TopLevel = false;
     panel_contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
     panel_contenedor.Tag = formulario;
     formulario.Show();
}
```

Este método actualmente solo permite abrir una sola instancia del mismo formulario, si al momento de invocar la opción el formulario no existe en el panel, lo muestra, y si el formulario existe entonces le hago un `BringToFront();` para ponerlo en primer plano.

Con esto realizo la busqueda del formulario dentro del panel.

```
  Form formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
```

---

**Menú**

Suponga que tengo el siguiente menú con las opciones:

MENU

- Proceso 1 (`Form1` Con 3 parámetros) (Permitir Varias Instancias)
- proceso 2 (`Form2` Sin parámetros) (**NO** Permitir Varias Instancias)
- Proceso 3 (`Form3` Con 1 Parámetros) (**NO** Permitir Varias Instancias)
- Proceso 4 (`Form1`)
- Proceso 5 (`Form1`)

La estructura de arriba significa lo siguiente: desde la opción del menú `Proceso1` hasta `Proceso3` son tres formularios distintos, y las opciónes del menú `Proceso4` y `Proceso5` son exactamente el mismo formulario (`Form1`).

> En pocas palabras la opción `Proceso 1` , `Proceso 4`, `Proceso 5` es un único formulario `Form1`. El cual se corportará de forma distinta dependiendo de que opción del menu sea llamado.

---

**Condiciónes o Restricciones**

Se me ocurre condicionarlo mediante un parámetro `bool permitirInstancias = true;`.

Las condiciones o restricciones que deben cumplir para permitir abrir varias instancias de un formulario son las siguiente:

1 - Si el formulario tiene el parámeto `permitirInstancias = true;`

2 - Si la propiedad Text  del formulario no es la misma que el que esta abierto por ejemplo:

- El `Form1` segun la opción invocada tiene diferente nombre en la propiedad `Text` en tiempo de ejecusión `Form1.Text = "Proceso1";`, `Form1.Text = "Proceso2";` etc...

---

**He intentado lo siguiente**

Supongo que podría usar `Any()` para condicionarlo, pero no sé como aplicar las dos restricciones mencionadas arriba, en cambio he hecho esto: Al método le he agregado el siguiente código:

```
Form formulario;
var control = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();

if (control != null)
{
    if (control.Name.Equals("Form1"))
        formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>() as Form;
    else
       formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
}
else
      formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
```

> Con esto de manera forzada estoy obligando a que si el formulario se llama `Form1` permita abrir varias instancias y funciona, pero aunque la porpiedad `Text` sea el mismo, abre el mismo formulario.

La llamada de las opciones del menú serian las siguiente:

```
   AbrirFormularios(() => new Form1("A", 1, true)); //Opcion: Proceso1 (true)  indica que si debe permitir varias instancias.
   AbrirFormularios(() => new Form2()); //Proceso2 (NO permite varias instancias)
   AbrirFormularios(() => new Form3("Parametro")); //Proceso3 (NO permite varias intancias)
   AbrirFormularios(() => new Form1("B", 1, true)); //Opcion: Proceso4
   AbrirFormularios(() => new Form1("C", 1, true)); //Opcion: Proceso5
```

> **¿Cómo podría bajo estas condiciones permitir que un formulario especifico si se pueda abrir mas de una vez dentro del panel?**

Comment: La verdad es que da gusto preguntas asi de claras, yo las pondría de ejemplo en el centro de ayuda. Enhorabuena.

Comment: El problema de tu pregunta es que estas obteniendo siempre el mismo formulario con FirstOrDefault, sin embargo lo que tienes que hacer es buscar el que coincide con el nombre del que estas pasando y trabajar con ese. O sea **Form formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().Where(it => it.Name.Equals(metodofactory().Name)).FirstOrDefault();**

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas he probado lo que plantea, sin embargo no funciona.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como te dije en un comentario en tu anterior pregunta,una manera muy sencilla sería usar la propiedad `Tag` del formulario.

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public void AbrirFormulario<T>(Func<T> metodofactory,string textoForm = "", bool multiplesInstancias=false) where T : Form
{
      //Buscar el formulario dentro del panel.
      Form formulario;

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textoForm))
          formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
        else 
          formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().Where(f => f.Text.Equals(textoForm)).FirstOrDefault();

      if (formulario != null)
      {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(formulario.Tag)) ||
             (bool)formulario.Tag==false || formulario.Text == textoForm)
         {
             //Si la instancia esta minimizada la dejamos en su estado normal
             if (formulario.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
             {
                  formulario.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
             }
             //Si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
             formulario.BringToFront();
             return;
         }              
     }

     //Se abre el form
     formulario = metodofactory();
     formulario.TopLevel = false;

     if (multiplesInstancias == true)
         formulario.Tag = multiplesInstancias;

     if (multiplesInstancias == true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textoForm))
         formulario.Text = textoForm;

     panel_contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
     panel_contenedor.Tag = formulario;
     formulario.BringToFront();
     formulario.Show();
}
```

Como ves,se añade un nuevo parámetro al método que recibirá si el formulario admitirá múltiples instancias, `multiplesInstancias` que tiene `false` como valor por omisión. El valor de este parámetro se añade al `Tag` del formulario al ser creado. Al comprobar si ya has una instancia de ese formulario, se comprueba si admite multiples instancias, y si no es asi se muestra el formulario que ya existe y se sale del método. En caso contrario, se crea uno nuevo.

**Edit:**

1- He colocado el parámetro `textoForm` como opcional en la función `textoForm = ""`. Esto porque no a todos los formularios le pondré el título mediante la función, esto solo será cuando el formulario deba permitir varias instancias.

2- Si el parámetro `textoForm` no esta en blanco entonces busco el formulario dentro del panel utilizando el método sugerido por `@Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas` con un ligero cambio de la propiedad `name` por la propiedad `Text`

```
formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().Where(f => f.Text.Equals(textoForm)).FirstOrDefault();
```

3- He agregado esta otra condición al `if` que valida el `tag` y el `textoForm` para el caso de los formularios que no permiten varias instancias.

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(formulario.Tag))
```

4- Solo agrego el `tag` al formulario si este permite varias instancias.

```
if (multiplesInstancias == true)
    formulario.Tag = multiplesInstancias;
```

5- Y por último solo le agrego el título al formulario, si este permite varias instancias y si el `textoForm` no esta en blanco.

```
if (multiplesInstancias == true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textoForm))
    formulario.Text = textoForm;
```

Listo!.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78006/discussion-on-answer-by-pikoh-como-permitir-abrir-varias-instancias-de-un-formu).