# Cómo puedo adaptar esta función para que funcione con (Async, Await, Task)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, async

Tengo la siguiente función, basada en una pregunta que realicé hace un tiempo aquí:

[¿Cómo permitir abrir varias instancias de un Formulario bajo cierta condición especificada?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167825/c%C3%B3mo-permitir-abrir-varias-instancias-de-un-formulario-bajo-cierta-condici%C3%B3n-es)

```
public void AbrirFormulario<T>(Func<T> metodofactory,string textoForm = "", bool multiplesInstancias=false) where T : Form
{
  //Buscar el formulario dentro del panel.
  Form formulario;

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textoForm))
      formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    else 
      formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().Where(f => f.Text.Equals(textoForm)).FirstOrDefault();

  if (formulario != null)
  {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(formulario.Tag)) ||
         (bool)formulario.Tag==false || formulario.Text == textoForm)
     {
         //Si la instancia esta minimizada la dejamos en su estado normal
         if (formulario.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
         {
              formulario.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
         }
         //Si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
         formulario.BringToFront();
         return;
     }              
 }

 //Se abre el form
 formulario = metodofactory();
 formulario.TopLevel = false;

 if (multiplesInstancias == true)
     formulario.Tag = multiplesInstancias;

 if (multiplesInstancias == true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textoForm))
     formulario.Text = textoForm;

 panel_contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
 panel_contenedor.Tag = formulario;
 formulario.BringToFront();
 formulario.Show();
}
```

La cual funciona perfectamente bien, pero al momento de ejecutarla por ejemplo:

```
AbrirFormulario(() => new Form1(true, "parametro2"), "Titulo", true);
```

Hasta que la función no termina de hacer todas las validaciones, mi interfaz (UI) esta bloqueada, me gustaría comenzar a usar (Async, Await, Task) en esta función de modo que cuando se ejecute dicha función trabaje, y pueda seguir usando mi interfaz.

Dicho esto, **¿Pueden ayudarme a adaptar esta función para que funcione con (Async, Await, Task) para trabajar de forma paralela?**

---

Mi entorno actual de trabajo es: **Visual Studio 2017 con .NetFrameWork 4.5.2**

> **Nota:** Nunca he usado (Async, Await, Task), se me dificulta un poco entenderlo, y me gustaría comenzar con esta función para entender su funcionamiento.

Comment: Ese método no debería bloquear el UI durante prácticamente nada de tiempo, ya que no realiza ninguna operación que sea costosa. Estás seguro de que es la culpable de que tu UI se bloquee?

Comment: el async/await no funciona si tienes una interfacion con el usuario, lo planteo porque alli veo que envias una Func<> que instancia un Form1, eso de forma asincrona no aplica

Comment: el metodo `AbrirFormulario()` que pones como ejemplos no es candidato a trabajar de forma asincrona

Comment: @Pikoh Por ejemplo tengo un formulario que tiene muchos Objetos en el mas de 200 controles y mientras carga ese formulario u otros, semejantes no me permite hacer nada mas en el menú principal

Comment: @LeandroTuttini ah, no sabía eso, como menciono, nunca he trabajo con (Async, Await, Task), pero entonces si no se puede, eliminaré la pregunta ya que no tendría sentido que este ;(

Comment: Como bien dice @LeandroTuttini, todo lo que trabaje con el UI debe estar en el hilo principal. Tal vez lo que debas hacer es crear algun tipo de barra de progreso/indicador de progreso que indique al usuario que debe esperar hasta que se cargue el formulario...

Comment: Aun asi, si solo es el proceso de carga antes de interactuar con el usuario, es posible que pudieras pasarlo a otro hilo...la verdad, nunca lo probé, pero teoricamente es posible

Comment: @Pikoh utilizo un tipo de progreso proporcionado por un control de DevExpress "SplashScreenManager.ShowOverlayForm" con Licencia, que se muestra mientras carga el formulario, pero igual se toma el tiempo en cargarlo un poco mas de lo que debería, como es lo de pasar a otro Hilo?

Comment: Me refiero a usar un `BackGroudWorker` o, como pides, `Task`. Pero tendría que probarlo, no se si funcionaría correctamente...

Comment: @Pikoh es que como BackGroudWorker ya esta dejando de ser usado me gustaría comenzar a trabajar con Task y ascyn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre que para solucionar tu problema, podes usar [Task.Run](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.5.2) junto con async/await y validando [InvokeRequired](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired?view=netframework-4.5.2) cuando sea necesario

```
public async Task AbrirFormulario<T>(Func<T> metodofactory, string textoForm = "", bool multiplesInstancias = false) where T : Form
{
    //Hago un await de la tarea
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Form formulario;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textoForm))
            formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
        else
            formulario = panel_contenedor.Controls.OfType<T>().Where(f => f.Text.Equals(textoForm))
                        .FirstOrDefault();

        if (formulario != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(formulario.Tag)) || (bool) formulario.Tag == false || formulario.Text == textoForm)
            {
                //Si la instancia esta minimizada la dejamos en su estado normal
                if (formulario.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {
                    formulario.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                }
                //Si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
                formulario.BringToFront();
                return;
            }
        }

        //Se abre el form
        formulario = metodofactory();
        formulario.TopLevel = false;

        if (multiplesInstancias == true)
            formulario.Tag = multiplesInstancias;

        if (multiplesInstancias == true && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textoForm))
            formulario.Text = textoForm;

        //Valido si es necesario usar un método de invocación o no
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            //En caso de serlo, utilizo Invoke para modificar el UI
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                panel_contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario); 
                panel_contenedor.Tag = formulario;
                formulario.BringToFront();
                formulario.Show();
            }));
        }
        //Caso contrario, lo modifico normalmente
        else
        {
            panel_contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
            panel_contenedor.Tag = formulario;
            formulario.BringToFront();
            formulario.Show();
        }
    });
}
```

Ahora, para llamar la función, por ejemplo en un botón

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await AbrirFormulario(() => new Form1(true, "parametro2"), "Titulo", true))
        .ContinueWith((c) => MessageBox.Show("El formulario terminó de cargar."));
}
```

Edit: Lo que refiere a duplicar el código, lo que se me ocurre es usar una función, algo así:

```
public void ModificarUI(Action action)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(action);
    else
        action();
}
```

Entonces después, cuando necesites, directamente lo llamas así

```
ModificarUI(() => {
            panel_contenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
            panel_contenedor.Tag = formulario;
            formulario.BringToFront();
            formulario.Show();
        });
```

Comment: No tengo total certeza de que de este modo se solucione tu problema, porfavor comentame como te va para dejar/eliminar la respuesta!

Comment: No, agregando task async awit, no implica procesamiento en paralelo, digo de esa manera el usuario de igual manera debera esperar, @JuanSalvador seria mejor eliminar tu respuesta.

Comment: No se porque han votado negativamente, pero esto ha funcionado para mi, en el sentido de que no bloquea la interfaz

Comment: @Rodrigues, Si revisas la pregunta y el comentario se esta trabajando con la Form que no se quiere bloquear, no se refiere a otro proceso independiente.

Comment: @MiguelZarate se que el procesamiento no es paralelo, la idea la respuesta es que no se bloquee la interfaz (entendí que ese era el problema en los comentarios)

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Aunque no funcione de forma paralela, como han comentado, ciertamente no bloquea la UI, y es lo que buscaba, aunque aquí solo puse una muestra de la función ya que es mas amplia que esta, lo único negativo que veo es: 
 `if (InvokeRequired) {  Invoke(new Action(() => { ///....... })); } else { ///..... }` tener que duplicar el código dentro de `Invoke` y en el `else`, aunque se que esto es para que no provoque la excepción de que se esta ejecutando en otro hilo, **Existe alguna forma de no tener que duplicar el código?**

Comment: @J.Rodríguez ahí edite la respuesta agregando lo que se me ocurre, igual estoy seguro que deben existir mejores soluciones dando vuelta por ahí

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Si, siempre hay una forma mas práctica de hacerlo, muchas gracias por haber tomado el tiempo de responder.